# Create multiple variable, assign attributes, assign values in a for loop

Tags: r, list, loops, variables, vector

I am looking to create a list of vectors to which I want to assign specific value. I know I can do something like

```
var_list=c(V1, V2...etc)
```

Then use var_list[i] in a for loops. To do this thought, I have to manually creates the list at first, which is long.
I know I can do something like

```
for(i in 1:n){
    assign(paste("Mx", i, sep = ""), i)
}
```

This will creates my variable name. Trouble is, how do I manage them? I would like a way to do something like this :

```
for(i in 1:n){
    attributes(assign(paste("Mx", i, sep = ""), i))<-list(dim=1:n)
    "here I would like to append the newly created variable (Mx"i") into a list so I could manage the whole thing later on".
}
```

So I could do :

```
for (k in 1:n){
for (j in 1:m)
new_list[[k]][j]<-other_list[[k]][(j-1)*3+1]
}
```

Any1 got a idea?
The basic problem is that I have this long list of vector (which is represented here by "other_list"). Each vector in this list has 36 entry. I want to divide each of these vector in three different vector (I need to specify the specific value of the vector from "other_list" I want to apply to the specific value of the vector of the " new_list ".
Thanks !

Comment: `assign` is not a function which should be used by beginners. It usually offers only an apparent solution that makes subsequent steps only harder for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just pre-allocate the list and assign its names:

```
n <- 10
#pre-allocate list
mylist <- vector(n, mode = "list")
#assign names
names(mylist) <- paste0("Mx", seq_len(n))

#fill the list
for(i in 1:n){
 mylist[[i]] <- i
}

mylist[1:3]
#$Mx1
#[1] 1
#
#$Mx2
#[1] 2
#
#$Mx3
#[1] 3
```

PS: You should learn to use `lapply` for such tasks.

```
setNames(lapply(seq_len(n), identity), paste0("Mx", seq_len(n)))
```

And the optimal solution for the specific example is this:

```
setNames(as.list(seq_len(n)), paste0("Mx", seq_len(n)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I did as you suggested but it did not work at the "assign names" step.
When I enter the code " names(mylist)<-paste0("Mx",seq_len(n)) " then run it, it doesn't show any warning message. Then I type in to display "mylist" in the console, and it displays it like this:
$<NA>
NULL
$<NA>
NULL

Comment: ... oh well, now it worked... I had erased all the memory thought. Thanks alot :)